# How to connect to on-premise VPN from EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpn, cisco

I would like to run my Node application from EC2. But my application's database is in Client's location and I usually connect through Cisco AnyConnect VPN application.

I tried installing openconnect in the EC2, the moment I connect to the VPN, the instance goes out of my control. I understood this, because I no longer have control on the EC2 instance, since it's in the Client's VPN network. So I rebooted the EC2 to get back the access.

So how can I connect my Client's VPN from EC2 ?

Note: I cannot install or ask my client to configure anything on their end for this, they just provided their VPN connection details.

Comment: So, you're really asking "How can I have a VPN connection between the EC2 instance and an on-premises computer while still allowing me to remain connected to the instance via the Internet"? It sounds like you'll need to configure [split tunnelling](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/100936-asa8x-split-tunnel-anyconnect-config.html).

Answer (score 0):

Create a Gateway in AWS.  You can build an IPsec tunnel from AWS to a client's firewall using a site-to-site VPN.